# an easy way to apply key combination to focussed window in Ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, window, focus

In the Accessibility settings of [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) in Ubuntu, there is the "Negative" effect which can toggle an active window negative (i.e., light colours of the window become dark and dark colours become light) through the use of a key combination (e.g. Super n). This effect is a Compiz plugin (`sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins`). I want to make this facility available easily to a user who is using a touchscreen to interact with the computer instead of a keyboard.

The way I envisage for the user to implement this facility is to select a launcher icon in the Unity Launcher which executes a small script. Then, the user selects the appropriate window and the script causes the window to toggle between negative and positive (likely by using the key combination for Compiz when it detects that a window has been selected and brought into focus). I have been experimenting with [xvkbd](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/) and [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html) (e.g. `xdotool key Super+n`), but I'm not sure how to detect when a window is selected and brought into focus. I am not inclined towards having the script wait for some amount of time and then simple using the key combination, affecting whatever window happens to be in focus.

So, how can I detect in a Python or Bash script when a window has been selected or brought into focus in Ubuntu Unity and how can I subsequently make it negative?

At present, I have a launcher which executes the following commands:

```
sleep 2
xdotool key Super+n
```

Comment: I would imagine you could look at the source code of CompizConfig, and see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Compiz applies the effect simply to the window in focus when the key combination is used. The difficulty is that the intended window may *not* be in focus when using a touchscreen *instead* of a keyboard.